# Internet on SmartPhone

Tags: internet, mobile-phone

I have a Nokia N7. and A PC with permanent DSL internet connection, with Nokia PC Suite latest version Installed.

A Data-Cable (for N72) and a blue-tooth dongle as well (with software and drivers installed).

I want to use my PC's Internet connection on my smart-phone - is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check to see if this [link](http://www.allaboutsymbian.com/forum/showthread.php?t=45477) helps

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.